# Picture puzzle.. numbers missing

Tags: pattern, visual

Below is a picture and a set of numbers. There are 6 question marks. Try replace them!

[image]

Comment: Did you create this puzzle yourself? If not, please provide recognition to the original author

Comment: Yes, this is my own creation.

Comment: Is the first number meant to be 1 digit longer than the rest?

Comment: @Bee Yes, it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $110111$

Reasoning

> First convert the binary numbers to decimal:
>  $64, 43, 36, 54,$ ????
>  Now, notice that there are five numbers and five shapes in the picture. Therefore, it's seems reasonable to guess that each number corresponds to a shape. With a little bit of thought I found that the first digit in each case corresponds to the number of letters in the colour of the shape and the second digit corresponds to the number of sides. Specifically, the correspondence is as follows:
>  $ 64 \leftrightarrow$ YELLOW, 4 sides (diamond)
>  $ 43 \leftrightarrow$ BLUE, 3 sides (triangle)
>  $ 36 \leftrightarrow$ RED, 6 sides (hexagon)
>  $ 54 \leftrightarrow$ BLACK, 4 sides (rectangle)
>  The only shape so far not included is the GREEN pentagon which would correspond to $55$ or $110111$, in binary.

Comment: You're absolutely right with the reasoning and the answer! Good job :)